# add a custom font to jquery CLeditor

Tags: javascript, cleditor

I use http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor in my projects and there is some font shown by default in font drop down list, now i have a font and want to use this font in cleditor font list and when user pick this font the font css apply to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most plugins there are options exposed and `fonts` is one property that you can set when you initialize plugin

```
$("#input").cleditor({               
            fonts: // font names in the font popup
                "Arial,Arial Black,Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Narrow,Garamond," +
                "Georgia,Impact,Sans Serif,Serif,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana"
})
```

See *Optional Parameters* in [Getting STarted](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/gettingstarted)

Comment: i know about that

Comment: so what is the problem? A brief relatively meaningless comment won't get you much additional help

Comment: but i want upload my font and this font does not exist in user pc.

Comment: i want something like font-face in css

Comment: Why was none of this mentioned in the question? Suggest you take some time to read through [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) then update the question with what your real problem is

Comment: You can load fonts from your site or other url on web also

Comment: @Rebwar no it isn't, you didn't identify what the real problem was and made the question vague so it can be interpreted various ways

Comment: guys my question is real clear, i have a font installed on my PC and i want  to add this font in cl edited font list and when i select that my custom font selected as a active font

Comment: and none of that is stated in the question and neither is any problem mentioned why it doesn't work when you add that font to the options list

Comment: my problem is i can't find how to add a new font to CLEDITOR plugin

Comment: why doesn't answer I gave work? you won't get much help around here if you aren't specific

Comment: dear charliet, you give me this:

Comment: $("#input").cleditor({               
            fonts: // font names in the font popup
                "Arial,Arial Black,Comic Sans MS,Courier New,Narrow,Garamond," +
                "Georgia,Impact,Sans Serif,Serif,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana"
})

Comment: and that answered the vague question. If you want a quality answer that fits the specific problem you need to write a quality question that properly details your issue ...period!

Comment: but this font install on all pc and these fonts are public for every one. but i want add a font like font-face in css and show in cleditor font list

Comment: And where does it say anything about that in the question? Use a link tag for the font and upload it to a publicly accessible server

Comment: the problem is : how to use link tag for that in cleditor

Comment: you put it in the page where you use the editor. I am done with these comments. Write a proper question that includes ***all of your concerns and issues***

Comment: @Rebwar you load the font like you would normally in CSS, and then in the font list in this answer, add the name there. WTF are you a VB6 programmer or something? Because we haven't had to install fonts on the client PC since the 90's